# How do you reshape a dataframe for columns to rows and rows to colums?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out a simple way of reshaping my dataframe such that the rows become the columns and the columns become the rows. Picture below of what I want to do (in general):

The methods available don't seem to quite do what I want, or do more complex operations. Maybe there's something obvious I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried .melt(), but that gave me a new index while the things I wanted as my index were spread across the rows.

I also tried .pivot() but couldn't see how to get that to do what I wanted either.

Comment: try transposing ie `.T`